# wp_update_post to set post IDs to drafts not working

Tags: array, wp-update-post, draft

Specifically WooCommerce Product Pages.

I'm using `WP_Query` to generate the array.

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'menu-order',
    'order' => 'asc',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' =>
    array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 7,
            'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ));
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
$ids = $wc_query->posts;
```

the array in `$ids` looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8700
    [1] => 2558
    [2] => 2579
    [3] => 2582
    [4] => 2588
    . . . . . .
```

I've tried both a `for loop`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $postcount; $i++) {
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $ids[$i], 'post_status'   =>  'draft'));
}
```

and a `foreach loop`

```
foreach($post_ids as $post_id) {
     $post = array( 'ID' => $ids, 'post_status' => 'draft' );
     wp_update_post($post);
}
```

Neither are working. The pages are still set to `Published`.

Anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your for loop, I think you're missing the $postcount variable... also there's a typo at $idss[$i] .... should be $ids[i] based on what you've shown.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $postcount; $i++) {
    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $ids[$i], 'post_status'   =>  'draft'));
}
```

That being said I'd just go with a foreach loop.

The mistake that you're making is the 2nd line.

```
<?php 
  $post_ids = $wc_query->posts;

  foreach($post_ids as $post => $post_id) {
    echo $post_id;
  }
?>
```

Assuming that results in a nice list of ID's, then I'd do the following:

```
 <?php 
  $post_ids = $wc_query->posts;

  foreach($post_ids as $post => $post_id) {
    echo $post_id;
    $arrPost = array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'draft' );
    wp_update_post($arrPost);
  }
?>
```

I'm afraid this is the best I can do without being able to access the files.

Remember `var_dump()` is your friend!